# Postgres select rows that do not have 2nd order association with attribute=something

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables, Meetings, MeetingFeatures and Features.
I want to select all the Meetings that do not have a feature with the name of "XX"

My first thought was something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, meeting_features.id 
FROM meetings 
   INNER JOIN meeting_features ON meetings.id=meeting_features.meeting_id 
   INNER JOIN features ON meeting_features.feature_id=features.id 
WHERE features.name != 'XX'
```

But this still returns rows with Meetings I don't want. Any help is appreciated.

Also tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM meetings
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM meetings
        INNER JOIN meeting_features ON meetings.id = meeting_features.meeting_id
        INNER JOIN features ON meeting_features.feature_id = features.id
        WHERE features.NAME = 'XX'
        )
```

Comment: `select distinct *` hardly makes sense. This will include the PK columns and therefore you won't have any duplicates in the result (by definition) that could be removed by the `distinct` operator. (plus you are selecting the `meating_features.id` column twice that way)

Comment: It appears: `NOT EXISTS()` is the solution.

Comment: @wildplasser tried this, maybe my syntax is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM meetings M1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM meetings M2
        INNER JOIN meeting_features MF
                ON M2.id = MF.meeting_id
        INNER JOIN features F
                ON MF.feature_id = F.id
        WHERE F.NAME = 'XX'
          AND M1.meeting_id = M2.meeting_id  -- miss this one
        )
```

The inner join way

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.* 
FROM meetings M
INNER JOIN meeting_features MF
        ON M.id = MF.meeting_id 
LEFT JOIN features F
       ON MF.feature_id = F.id 
WHERE F.NAME <> 'XX'
  AND MF.feature_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me why we need that line? And maybe a good book to read on SQL?

Comment: The outter `SELECT` will give you all meeting. The `INNER SELECT` will give you those meeting with some feature `NAME = 'XX'` filtering with that line you check that exact meeting

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM meetings m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM meeting_features mf 
        JOIN features f ON mf.feature_id = f.id AND f.name = 'XX'
        WHERE m.id = mf.meeting_id
        );
```